# Error Building Airflow On Windows Using docker-compose

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am trying to run airflow on my windows machine using docker. Here is the link that I am following from the official doc - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/start/docker.html.

I have created the directory structure as expected and also downloaded the docker-compose yaml file. On running  'docker-compose up airflow-init' as suggested by documentation. I get below error

```
airflow-init_1       |
airflow-init_1       | [2021-07-03 10:19:29,721] {cli_action_loggers.py:105} WARNING - Failed to log action with (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "log" does not exist
airflow-init_1       | LINE 1: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_dat...
airflow-init_1       |                     ^
airflow-init_1       |
airflow-init_1       | [SQL: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_date, owner, extra) VALUES (%(dttm)s, %(dag_id)s, %(task_id)s, %(event)s, %(execution_date)s, %(owner)s, %(extra)s) RETURNING log.id]
airflow-init_1       | [parameters: {'dttm': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 3, 10, 19, 29, 712157, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'dag_id': None, 'task_id': None, 'event': 'cli_upgradedb', 'execution_date': None, 'owner': 'airflow', 'extra': '{"host_name": "7f142ce11611", "full_command": "[\'/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow\', \'db\', \'upgrade\']"}'}]
```

From the logs its clear that the log table does not exists and airflow is trying to insert into it. Not sure though why or how this error can be fixed. I am using the original docker-compose file that is published on airflow doc page.

This is the current status of my airflow docker image

[image]

on trying to access the airflow UI using - http://localhost:8080/admin/

I get Airflow 404=lot of circles error

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning because airflow CLI tries to add an audit log to log table before the tables get created.

I have the same warning on a fresh DB initially, but then the ouptu continues.

The output should continue and you should get something like that at the end (I run it with just released 2.1.1 which I recommend you to start with):

```
airflow-init_1       | [2021-07-03 15:54:01,449] {manager.py:784} WARNING - No user yet created, use flask fab command to do it.
airflow-init_1       | Upgrades done
airflow-init_1       | [2021-07-03 15:54:06,899] {manager.py:784} WARNING - No user yet created, use flask fab command to do it.
airflow-init_1       | Admin user airflow created
airflow-init_1       | 2.1.1
```

Comment: Added more details on my question

Answer (score 1):

Need to initialize the airflow dB

```
docker exec -ti airflow-webserver airflow db init && echo "Initialized airflow DB"
```

Create Admin user

```
docker exec -ti airflow-webserver airflow users create --role Admin --username {AIRFLOW_USER} --password {AIRFLOW_PASSWORD) -e {AIRFLOW_USER_EMAIL} -f {FIRST_NAME} -l {LAST_NAME} && echo "Created airflow admin user"
```